# Wrong parent selected from Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, function, delegation

First of: I am new to Javascript and trying to learn the principles.

I am trying to create a simple ToDo app in Javascript. It's almost working but I am stalling on the following:

When I add a task an HTML component gets appended to an UL for incompleted tasks. When I try to delete it, it always deletes the last LI in the list. Same goes for editting. When I click edit it always shows the edit input for the last LI in the uncompleted list.

Code here & working example here: 
http://tinyurl.com/gw29re9

I know it's a chunk of code. But could someone maybe take a look at it? I can't seem to figur out what I am doing wrong.

function locations:

- bind events to delete & edit buttons @rule 74, 89
- Delete parent & Edit function @rule 25, 32

Comment: http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations will probably explain what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, will read :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you place Eventlistners in a loop you should do it like that:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   (function (index) {
       eventlistner...
   })(i);
}
```

Comment: Holy crap it works...can you elaborate on how this fixes it?  https://jsfiddle.net/ocpjpbrv/5/